# In Developer command prompt for VS2017, cannot open witadmin.exe directly

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Usually with a "Developer command prompt for Visual Studio" you can directly use witadmin tool for administering TFS Work item changes as the "developer command prompt" adds the required environment variables.

witadmin for VS 2017 path is different than the previous versions. And this new path is not set with the "2017 developer command prompt". I have to use the witadmin.exe path in the 'developer command prompt'. Has Microsoft missed to update the corresponding batch file to set the new path to witadmin?

I am currently setting the new path with below command in the developer command prompt:

*set "PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;%PATH%"*

Comment: What's the specific version of VS2017 do you use? Checked version `15.6.4` and `15.8.1` both working as expected. Cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am using 15.8.4 and I had to install only VS 2017 Team Explorer..

Comment: So, the issue was resolved by installing the VS 2017 Team Explorer? right?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: Nope.. I installed only "VS 2017 Team Explorer" and not full Visual Studio.. With this "team explorer only" installation I have got witadmin tool.. however the developer command prompt is not having the 'path to witadmin' added to the PATH env variable..

Comment: Well, you need to install the full version of VS2017, generally it will automatically sets the environment variables for you, otherwise you cannot use it by default as related SDKs missed....you have to set the environment variables manually just as you did. Please see [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) for details.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: Thank you.. please post it as an answer to close this question..

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: I also feel that since with Team Explorer only installation, witadmin tool is getting installed, the path to the tool should also be reflecting automatically with developer command prompt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to install the full version of VS2017, generally it will automatically sets the environment variables for you, otherwise you cannot use it by default as related SDKs missed....you have to set the environment variables manually just as you did. Please see [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) for details.

The Team Explorer is just a component/plugin for visual studio, it relies on the VS...